# What is the radius of convergence of the power series?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the following power series and I would like to figure out the radius of convergence:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I appreciate any help&explanation.

Jacky

Comment: Are you aware of any test you could use to do so?

Comment: Your power series is also known as $\cos(x)-1$. It converges on the entire complex plane.

Comment: What is exactly that plane numerically?

Comment: @Jacky: Don't worry about it. The upshot is that it converges everywhere (has infinite radius of convergence). See my answer for a hint at how to show this.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|={}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x)^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!}}{(-1)^n\frac{(x)^{2n}}{(2n)!}}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|^{2}}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=0 \quad for \ all \ x\in \mathbb{R}.$$ 
So it is convergent for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Make the substitution $t=x^2,$ so that the series becomes $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}t^n.$$ Now try using the ratio test to determine for which $t$ this converges. That will tell you for which $x$ this converges.